# TODO app with dependencies

Tags: android, web-apps, project-management

I'm looking for a TODO app with dependency support. My requirements:

- Android and web version
- subtasks support
- cloud sync
- dependency - one task could depend on another
- automatic due dates - if task 1 depend on task 2, task 2 due date is automaticly set to task 1 due date

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you investigate [these](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17173/a-todo-app-that-allows-specifying-task-duration-and-more)? BTW If you have investigated any and found that they don't meet your criteria, it helps mentioning them in your question.

Comment: And while waiting for good answers: my list of [Todo Apps with Synchronisation](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo#group_22) might be a starter where at least your "cloud sync" requirement is met by all candidates, helping you to narrow down the list of candidates ;)

Comment: From the list, it seems that there is no app for me :(

Comment: @Fido You may find useful some things I list in this question of mine: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25483/mind-mapping-tool-that-supports-many-parents-or-task-manager-tool-that-supports